# Is there any way to get the Windows key in an answer using <kbd>?

Tags: support, kbd

Really, title says it all.

I can only do <kbd>WIN</kbd>.

I want:

[image]

Comment: Most people just type the word `Windows`...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HOLY CRAP ONE CAN HAVE IMAGES INSIDE KBD TAGS THIS IS A NEW BEGINNING

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Edit: Even in colour!

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And with transparency!

<kbd>[image: THE END IS NEAR / THE PRINCESS IS IN ANOTHER CASTLE / ABANDON HOPE]</kbd>

Comment: NOBODY TELL JEFF

Comment: The keyboard element has always allowed images.

Comment: For anyone that wants the history of Windows logos, in case they want to make something *really* abhorrent: http://logos.wikia.com/wiki/Windows#2012-present

Comment: Also note: please, if you do use an image in a legitimate post, make it a standard 16x16 logo so it's not incredibly bulky and makes the post look like crap. If you don't, others *will* replace it with text.

Comment: +1 for the alt text in the last image.

Comment: @Pekka on to the next castle!

Answer (score 3):

[image] <sup>⇒ <kbd>shift</kbd>⇒ <kbd>F1</kbd></sup>

Comment: I don't actually know what you mean by that

Comment: @jdotjdot For keyboards that don't have a windows key, shift and f1 will do the same thing.

Comment: @casperOne shouldn't it be `Ctrl + Esc` to open the Start Menu?

Comment: @cychoi I suppose it is now.